# Improve performance in spring boot web service by making asynchronous calls to other APIs

Tags: java, spring-boot, asynchronous, completable-future

I am building a Spring Boot REST service that calls other REST APIs to get data. I have to call a REST API (API A) and based on its output call two other REST APIs (API B & C). "API A" supports pagination so I can pass it a start count and fetch size to get a specific set of data.

Currently I call the "API A" in a loop with fetch size of 200 (till it returns empty response). After each call, I then call API B and API C sequentially. I call API B with a fetch size of 200 (same as API A). API C supports only one input so I loop through API A output and call it once for each row. All these sequential calls are causing my API to take very long to send back a response. Though I am currently calling API A with a fetch size of 200 and it returns in 2 seconds, I would like to reduce this time by making asynchronous calls to API A with a smaller fetch size.

I am planning to rearrange my code as below:

1. Call API A 5 times (async calls) with fetch size of 40.
2. After each call completes - call API B and API C (again async calls)
3. Check if the 5th call (to API A) returned an empty response. If not then fire another 5 asynchronous calls to API A to get next set of data (step 1)
   Few more constraints:
   API B performs well for a fetch size of 100. So I do not want to call API B after every call to API A returns. Instead I would like to add up the API A responses (in a list) and call API B only once the size reaches 100. Basically the fetch size of API A and API B should be independent of each other.

I trying to figure out a logic to do above using Completable Future (or any other method) but it ends up feeling very complex. So I am not able to finalize a basic code structure that I should follow.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want can be achieved using the Spring WebClient from the [spring-webflux](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web-reactive.html) library (see https://www.baeldung.com/spring-5-webclient how to use that client).

The WebClient is the follower of Springs RestTemplate can works reactive in a non-blocking way.

Answer (score 0):

Do the calls to API B and C depend on the prior calls? If not you could call them asynchronously and in parallel with the mentioned WebClient using [Mono.zip()](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#zip-java.util.function.Function-reactor.core.publisher.Mono...-)

Comment: No API B and C do not depend on prior calls. To use mono I would have to use web flux right?

Comment: Can I use web flux only for the WebClient while the rest of the application is Spring MVC?. Other parts of the API are being worked on by different team members, so I want to make a change that does not impact them. Any suggestions on doing this without using web flux?

Comment: Yes you can use the WebClient for outgoing calls within a servlet environment, see the [13. WebClient for Servlet Environments](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.1.1.RELEASE/reference/html/servlet-webclient.html). You would need to resolve the Mono (e.g. with `yourMono.block()`) obviously before you return the response to the user since the rest of the flow is synchronous.